# How did "am" turn into "are"?

Tags: grammar, history

Is there any historical grammar explanation why in the tag questions "am" changes into "aren't?"For example, "I'm a teacher, aren't I"? The personal pronoun "I" relates to the first singular person and is used with "am", but in the second part of the sentence there is "aren't" which goes usually with plural forms.Why can't it be "I'm a teacher, am not I"?

Comment: *They sang every morning how lucky **we am**, To live in a windmill in old Amsterdam*

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a remodelling of a form *an't*, contracted from the awkward *amn't*.

The OED says (s.v. ***be***, section *etymology 2.1*):

> The forms *an’t* and *ain’t* , when functioning as 1st singular, perhaps
>   represent a contraction of *am* with the negative particle  ... *an’t* and *ain’t*
>   were subsequently reanalysed as equivalent to *are not* , and the
>   spelling *aren’t* superseded *an’t* in standard English, leading to
>   avoidance not only of *I aren’t* but also of *aren’t I* by some speakers
>   of current English.